# Delegate method is not calling in the Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

iPadApp:i have a two classes `TimeTableViewController` and `MLCViewController` created a protocol in `MLCViewController` and that protocol i want to call in the `TimeTableViewController` . But the `delegate(protocol)` method is not calling in the `TimeTableViewController`.

Here is my code…….

In **MLCViewController.h**

```
//created protocol

@protocol MLCCancelDelegate;

@protocol MLCCancelDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

-(void)CancelMLCSession;

@end

@property(nonatomic,weak)id <MLCCancelDelegate>Mlcdelegate;
```

**MLCViewController.m**

```
//Which is written in a UIAlertView Delegate method
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
        {

            if (self.Mlcdelegate && [self.Mlcdelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(CancelMLCSession)])
            {
                [self.Mlcdelegate CancelMLCSession];
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

In **TimeTableViewController.m**

```
//ViewDidLoad
 self.fifthViewController=[[MLCViewController alloc]init];
    fifthViewController.Mlcdelegate = self;

//-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                    UIViewController* vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MLCNote"];


                    pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
                    pc.delegate = self;


                    [pc presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:collectionData
                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                      animated:YES];


//Iam calling that delegate method like

-(void)CancelMLCSession{

    NSLog(@"cancelling");

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the second code block has to do with the first.  Please clarify.

Comment: when i click on the didselectrow Ppup will come and the MLCViewcontroller will call.In that MLCViewController i wrote delegate method.

Comment: that delegate method i called in TimeTABLEVIEWCONTROLLER WHICH IS SECOND BLOCK

Comment: is `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MLCNote"];` creates an instance of `MLCViewController`?

Comment: Yes it creates the instance of MLCViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD this code

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                    self.fifthViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MLCNote"];
                    pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.fifthViewController];
                    pc.delegate = self;
                    self.fifthViewController.Mlcdelegate=self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
self. before fifthViewController.Mlcdelegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MLCViewController* vc = (MLCViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MLCNote"];
vc.Mlcdelegate = self;
self.fifthViewController = vc;

//rest stuff
```